# Unable to expose previously created persistent snapshot

Tags: windows, backup, snapshot

When working with VSS following problem arises.
We create a persistent snapshot of disk volume (e.g. vshadow -p -script=snapshot.cmd f:). Creation is successful and snapshot is visible (vshadow -q). Then we restart the computer. After rebooting the snapshot is still visible, but it is not possible to perform the operation expose (e.g. vshadow.exe –el=%SHADOW_ID_1%, "c:\test1" returns an error). Snapshot removal performed without errors.

```
VSHADOW.EXE 3.0 - Volume Shadow Copy sample client. Copyright (C) 2005 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(Option: Expose a shadow copy)
- Setting the VSS context to: 0xffffffff
- Exposing shadow copy {865abd59-ddbd-46b0-aae8-cfd350b85862} under the path 'c: \ test1'
- Checking if 'c: \ test1 \' is a valid empty directory ...

ERROR: COM call "m_pVssObject-> ExposeSnapshot (snapshotID, NULL, VSS_VOLSNAP_ATTR_EXPOSED_LOCALLY, (VSS_PWSZ) path.c_str () , & PwszExposed) "failed.
- Returned HRESULT = 0x80042302
- Error text: VSS_E_UNEXPECTED
- Please re-run VSHADOW.EXE with the / tracing option to get more details
```

Without rebooting snapshot creation and exposing work without errors.
Testing was done on Windows 2012 on a few VSS hardware providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reboot iscsi target does not automatically connect, so vss unable to find device during expose.